# Deploy Metadata with Apex Testing Using REST returns 500 error

Tags: rest-api, metadata-api

I am trying to [deploy Metadata on Salesforce using REST api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_rest_deploy.htm). Here is my request:

`POST https://myorg-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v55.0/metadata/deployRequest`

headers :

`{Authorization: "Bearer 00D...", "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------BOUNDARY"}`

```
----------------------------BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"; Content-Type: application/json
{
  "deployOptions":
    {
      "allowMissingFiles": false,
      "autoUpdatePackage": false,
      "checkOnly": false,
      "ignoreWarnings": false,
      "performRetrieve": false,
      "purgeOnDelete": false,
      "rollbackOnError": false,
      "runTests": null,
      "singlePackage": true,
      "testLevel": "RunAllTestsInOrg"
    }
}
----------------------------BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="deploy.zip"
Content-Type: application/zip
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----------------------------BOUNDARY--
```

*NB : I truncated the base64 encoded zip file to simplify the explanation here.*

I can't contact Salesforce support service because I am using the Salesforce Developer Edition; it does not offer support.

The API response gives a 500 error :

`[{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 926862273-8617 (-291109249)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}]`

So I have no clue what the problem is.
My only guess would be that perhaps the zip, base64-encoded, is in the wrong format. But other than that I really don't know what could be the problem.

Do you have any idea on what the problem is ?

Knowing that I don't have access to customer support, do you know how I could debug that ?

Comment: Please include the complete [GACK ID](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/tag/gack) in your question instead of 9268...

Comment: Hi @Swetha, just edited my post to add the full GACK ID

Comment: Obviously a 500 is tough to debug without access to the server on which the error occurred. But are you perhaps deploying stuff that breaches a limit somewhere, either within the org or on the Metadata API?

Comment: Depending on how much stuff you are deploying, you may need to selectively remove stuff until you have a working deployment, or start with a small deployment and add stuff until it stops working

Comment: hi @dyson, thank you for your help, AFAICS I'm not breaching any limit; my zip is only 4KB and has 2 files, whereas the limit is 10,000 files or 39MB.

I've also tried to remove parts of my deployment payload one by one until I get a working deployment request, even tried to send an empty deployment request, but none of these ideas worked, always returning a 500 error.

Comment: Based on the salesforce backend logs, I see that the stacktrace Id `291109249 `points to  `lib.gack.GackContext: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Hi @Swetha thank you for your help ! this log alone doesn't explain much, do you have access to any other information ?

Comment: did you try to deploy the file via Workbench as an alternative?

Comment: Hi @cropredy, thank you for the suggestion, but long story short, Workbench does not seem to be a good fit for our use case. So far, the only fitting solution we found is to use REST API for Metadata.

Comment: Curious: What happens if you change this line: `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"; Content-Type: application/json` to be two separate lines - one: `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"` and one: `Content-Type: application/json`?

Comment: @Moonpie it gives the same output :(

Comment: Oh well. I've never deployed this way, so was just comparing your details with that found in the docs you linked to. The only other things I see that are really different pertain to your headers: 1) you show yours in a JSON object, whereas the docs do not; 2) your JSON appears to be "malformed" in that your `Authorization` property is not in quotes.

Comment: @UjCorb : Did you get this figured out? If so, please add an answer - it could help someone else later.

Comment: @Moonpie still no success... I'm using the bearer token without quotes in Postman, and JSON object is identical to the one in the example given in the official doc. I really have no clue what else I could try unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally made it work.

In my request body, each end of line is made of a "new line" character : `\n`.

Turns out I had to add a carriage return (`\r`) and a new line character together at each end of line in order to make it work : `\r\n`.

See [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433188/what-is-the-difference-between-r-n-r-and-n#:%7E:text=A%20carriage%20return%20(%20%5Cr%20),the%20beginning%20of%20that%20line.) for more info on those characters.

I wrote my request in Ruby, here is a sample. You can adapt it to any programming language you want :

```
    zipfile_path = generate_tmp_metadata_deploy_package

    uri = URI.parse("#{my_domain}/services/data/v56.0/metadata/deployRequest")
    boundary = "--------------------------BOUNDARY"
    header = {
      Authorization: "Bearer #{my_access_token}",
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=#{boundary}"
    }
    post_body = []
    post_body << "--#{boundary}\r\n"
    post_body << "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"json\"\r\n"
    post_body << "Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
    post_body << "\r\n"
    post_body << "{\r\n"
    post_body << "\"deployOptions\" :\r\n"
    post_body << "{\r\n"
    post_body << "\"allowMissingFiles\" : false,\r\n"
    post_body << "\"autoUpdatePackage\" : false,\r\n"
    post_body << "\"checkOnly\" : false,\r\n"
    post_body << "\"ignoreWarnings\" : false,\r\n"
    post_body << "\"performRetrieve\" : false,\r\n"
    post_body << "\"purgeOnDelete\" : false,\r\n"
    post_body << "\"rollbackOnError\" : false,\r\n"
    post_body << "\"runTests\" : null,\r\n"
    post_body << "\"singlePackage\" : true,\r\n"
    post_body << "\"testLevel\" : \"RunAllTestsInOrg\"\r\n"
    post_body << "}\r\n"
    post_body << "}\r\n"
    post_body << "----------------------------BOUNDARY\r\n"
    post_body << "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"#{File.basename(zipfile_path)}\"\r\n"
    post_body << "Content-Type: application/zip\r\n"
    post_body << "\r\n"
    post_body << File.read(zipfile_path)
    post_body << "\r\n----------------------------BOUNDARY--\r\n"

    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, header)
    request.body = post_body.join

    http.request(request)
```